# Copying Files from Subfolders Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a vba macro which will copy all excel files in the source folder which contains several sub folders. These files will need to be copied into one destination folder (without sub folders).

So far I have managed to copy the entire folder including the sub folders to the destination folder. How can I edit my code so that it only copies .xls files and pastes them without sub folders.

```
Sub PerformCopy()
==================== call ================================
MkDir "DestinationPath"

CopyFiles "Source Path With All Subfolders" & "\", "DestinationPath" & "\"

==================== Copy sub ===========================
End Sub


Public Sub CopyFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal strTarget As String)
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FileInFromFolder As Object
Dim FolderInFromFolder As Object
Dim Fdate As Long
Dim intSubFolderStartPos As Long
Dim strFolderName As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
'First loop through files
    For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(strPath).Files
        Fdate = Int(FileInFromFolder.DateLastModified)
        'If Fdate >= Date - 1 Then
            FileInFromFolder.Copy strTarget
        'end if
    Next

    'Next loop throug folders
    For Each FolderInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(strPath).SubFolders
        'intSubFolderStartPos = InStr(1, FolderInFromFolder.Path, strPath)
        'If intSubFolderStartPos = 1 Then

        strFolderName = Right(FolderInFromFolder.PATH, Len(FolderInFromFolder.PATH) - Len(strPath))
        MkDir strTarget & "\" & strFolderName

        CopyFiles FolderInFromFolder.PATH & "\", strTarget & "\" & strFolderName & "\"

    Next 'Folder

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like below, it uses your initial loop within your Folder loop to iterate through each file and copy into your destination folder:

```
Sub PerformCopy()
'==================== call ================================
'MkDir "DestinationPath"

CopyFiles "Source Path With All Subfolders" & "\", "DestinationPath" & "\"

'==================== Copy sub ===========================
End Sub


Public Sub CopyFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal strTarget As String)
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FileInFromFolder As Object
Dim FolderInFromFolder As Object
Dim Fdate As Long
Dim intSubFolderStartPos As Long
Dim strFolderName As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
'First loop through files
    For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(strPath).Files
        Fdate = Int(FileInFromFolder.DateLastModified)
            FileInFromFolder.Copy strTarget
    Next

    'Next loop throug folders
    For Each FolderInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(strPath).SubFolders
            For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(FolderInFromFolder).Files
                    FileInFromFolder.Copy strTarget
            Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Xabier. It seems to be working for a couple of files then I get Runtime Error 70: Permission Denied. Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: @msmand, could it be that some of them files are already open, Read Only, or even protected? Not sure what might be causing the issue, but you will probably find the cause by stepping through the code and seeing which file is actually giving you the error... It could also be that some hidden file is causing it, might be worth while checking the extension of the file before copying it to make sure it is an Excel file and not a system file.

Comment: thank you for your response. It turns out it was a network issue causing the error. I have tested your code with local folders and files and it works fine. Many thanks!